# Password generator generates the same passwords

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

I'm trying to make a password generator in Python but I have some problems with it.

My code is down below:

```
import random
import time

f = open("password_list.txt", "a+")

start = time.time()
password = ""
chars= "123456789"
number = int(input("Number of passwords to generate? = "))
length = int(input("Password length? = "))

for p in range(number):
    password = ""
    for c in range(length):
        password += random.choice(chars)
    print(password)
    f.write(password + "\n") 

print('time: ' + str((time.time() - start)) + ' sec')

f.close()
```

Everything works fine but the only problem is sometimes it generates the same passwords in the text file. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your English is fine.  However, we expect minimal code we can paste and run to produce the problem you specified.  Your code requires manual input, and you say that the problem is only "sometimes".  Replace your input statements with simple assignments, using one or more test cases that show the problem.  Also print the result, rather than writing it to a file, since file output is unrelated to your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help too, You guys are really making this community great.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid the duplication issue is to put the passwords into a `set` in your loop, and keep looping until the length of the set is the number of passwords you want to generate. Then you can write the contents of the set to the file. This shows how to generate the set of passwords:

```
import random

chars= "123456789"
number = 5
length = 8
passwords = set()

while len(passwords) < number:
    password = ""
    for c in range(length):
        password += random.choice(chars)
    passwords.add(password)

print(passwords)
```

Sample output:

```
{'67824479', '67159221', '78423732', '77922952', '83499619'}
```